# Why I am getting a conflict?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, functional-dependencies, polyvariadic

So I typed this up

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}

import Data.Monoid

class Monoid m => Mconcat m a | a -> m where
    mcon :: m -> a

instance Monoid m => Mconcat m m where
    mcon m = m

instance Mconcat m a => Mconcat m (m -> a) where
    mcon m m' = mcon (m `mappend` m')
```

and I get

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( pad.hs, interpreted )

pad.hs:8:10:
    Functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations:
      instance Monoid m => Mconcat m m -- Defined at pad.hs:8:10
      instance Mconcat m a => Mconcat m (m -> a)
        -- Defined at pad.hs:11:10
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

The thing is though, `m` and `m->a` cannot be equal! Why is it giving me a conflict? (Also, any tips as to how to make a polyvariadic mconcat (in the style of the `printf` library)?

Comment: Substitute `m -> a` for `m` in the first instance.

Comment: @ReidBarton oh, duh. For some reason I thought that wouldn't break it.

Comment: You can make this compile, and potentially do what you want (although I'm not sure what that is so I'm not quite sure) if you change the 2nd instance to `instance (Mconcat m a, o ~ (m -> a)) => Mconcat m o` - this requires `UndecidableInstances`. An `OverlappingInstances` or an `OVERLAPS` pragma for later versions on the 2nd instance.

Comment: @user2407038 I am trying to make a polyvariadic mconcat. See https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/423s5i/how_do_you_make_a_polyvardiac_mconcat/

Comment: @PyRulez Oh i see.. well in that case it works with the afformentioned change - `mcon "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" == "abcde"`

Answer (score 3):

You can make this compile and do what you want by changing the second instance declaration and adding `UndecidableInstances`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-} 
...
instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} (Mconcat m a, o ~ (m -> a)) => Mconcat m o where
```

or on earlier versions of GHC this should work (untested)

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances, OverlappingInstances #-} 
...
instance (Mconcat m a, o ~ (m -> a)) => Mconcat m o where
```

This works because GHC only looks at the head of an instance to determine if it satisfies the [coverage condition](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#flexible-instance-head), but you can (almost) always achieve the same instance by making this transformation. It even handles polymorphic cases!

```
>:set +t
>mcon [1] [2] [34,34,2,53] [34,23,43]
[1,2,34,34,2,53,34,23,43]
it :: Num t => [t]
>mcon "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
"abcde"
it :: [Char]
```

Comment: I bet this would make a good addition to an html library (so you don't have to abuse `do` notation).

Comment: Type inference often struggles quite a bit with variadic functions, which often makes them less than useful in practice. I'm surprised it does so well in this case. It may be the new `OverlappingInstances` machinery that does it... but I don't quite understand it, so I don't know.